# TestCafe - Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 10 Input text issue

Tags: javascript, windows-10, internet-explorer-11, e2e-testing, testcafe

My testcafe test inputs text into text fields using Internet Explorer but when it does it removes every other letter when inputting the text.

For Example: `test@something.com` would be entered as `ts@oehn.cm`

```
await t.typeText(Selector('#email'), 'myemail@email.com')

await t.typeText(Selector('#password'), 'mypassword')

await t.click(Selector('.account-form__button'))

await t.wait(6000);
```

Is this something someone has seen? The same test works fine in firefox and chrome on Windows.

Comment: I tried this scenario with sample markup:
 
`<body><input type="text" id="email"/><br/><input type="text" id="password"/><br/><div contenteditable="true" id="editable"></div></body>`
 
It passes in IE and I didn't notice any issues with deleting symbols. Could you please clarify which TestCafe version you are using? If your version is not the latest, could you please update it? Do you type text into input fields or contentEditable elements? Do you use any custom JS code editors?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to check this scenario with sample markup as follows:

```
<body>
  <input type="text" id="email"/><br/>
  <input type="text" id="password"/><br/>
  <div contenteditable="true" id="editable"></div>
</body>
```

This test passes in IE and I didn't notice any issues with deleting symbols. I recommend that you check out the latest testcafe version, 0.23.3 to see if this behavior is reproducible there.
 
If you think that you faced a bug, I recommend that you create a new issue and fill in all fields at https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md

Answer (score 1):

This problem could be related to the speed of typing and event handlers that are attached to the input field: these event handlers execute slower than input keyup/keydown frequency. The workaround is to type text like a real user (ie letter by letter):

```
const selector = Selector('#email');
const letters = [...'myemail@email.com'];
let index = -1;
for (const letter of letters) {
    index += 1;
    if (index === 0) {
        await t.typeText(selector, letter, {replace: true});
        continue;
    }
    await t
        .wait(100)
        .typeText(selector, letter);
}
```